An Algebra Question with 3 Variables and 3 Conditions to be met for Real Answers.
The question is as follows:
Solve for real numbers:
$$\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\sqrt x\right)\left(1+2\sqrt x\right)\left(1+4\sqrt x\right)}=1+2\sqrt y$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\sqrt y\right)\left(1+2\sqrt y\right)\left(1+4\sqrt y\right)}=1+2\sqrt z$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\sqrt z\right)\left(1+2\sqrt z\right)\left(1+4\sqrt z\right)}=1+2\sqrt x$$
Taking $\sqrt x$ as $a$, $\sqrt{y}$ as $b$ and $\sqrt z$ as $c$, I cubed LHS and RHS of all equations and brought everything to the lhs equating to $0$. Then I added every equation to get:
$$2a^2+2b^2+2c^2+a+b+c=0$$
Past that I am not sure what to do to get individual variables.
Edit: I got values for all 3 variables from this equation as 0, yet I wanted to confirm that there are none other possible real answers. I have tried only 1 method of solving that addition.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Your $a$, $b$, $c$ are non-negative quantities. A sum of non-negative quantities evaluates to 0 in only one case.

While Randy Marsh is completely correct for this problem, more generally, when you added the equations together to get the indicated equation, that does not mean that the earlier equations are no longer needed. At least two of the equations are clearly independent of each other, as they contain different variables. The third is likely independent of the other two (though that would have to be checked). A system of 3 independent equations does not reduce to a single equation. You threw information away by discarding the earlier equations.
